# Как расположить блоки таким образом?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как расположить блоки, как на фото? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы блоки были строго выровнены относительно один одного, были отступы, адаптивность.
Через FLexbox или Grid? Или еще есть варианты? Как будет лучше?

Comment: и грид и флекс легко справятся с этой задачей

Comment: Контейнер флексовый, с этими карточками, каждая карточка тоже флексовый элемент, у карточки `flex-direction: column;` и `justify-content: space-between`, чтобы элементы приклеились к краям блока. Т.е. в карточке будут вложены два блока, верхний и нижний, а внутри можно дописать им

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.container__inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -15px;
}

.container__item {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 33.333333333%;
}

.container__item:nth-child(1) {
  width: 66.666666666%;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__inner">
    <div class="container__item">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container__item">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container__item">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container__item">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container__item">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```